# Is there any verb meaning "evolve towards a final state"?

Tags: synonyms

I am currently working on some documentation, and I find myself having to express to idea of *evolving towards a final state* multiple times.
I would like to know if a word (preferably a verb) expressing this whole concept exists already.

As far as I know, evolving feels more like something which can be done perpetually, while I would like to carry the idea that evolving in such a case have its "boundaries".
Eventually, if it is not a single word, maybe there is a formal way to shorten the whole concept?

Another idea could be something like "growing", since growing feels more physical, hence necessarily has boundaries, but it does not fit my context:

*e.g.*:

> this transaction can  <strike>evolve towards its final state</strike> *grow* by requesting actions over it. You do so by either requesting a cancellation or actually capturing the funds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Evolve* isn't all that bad.  *Continue*?  *Proceed*?  *Iterate*?

Comment: Thanks, I just feel like I need to get rid of "towards its final state" since I find my self repeating the phrase a bit too often. Do you think I can simply use "evolve"? Does it make it implicit that the goal is a final state?

Comment: Well, there is the word *mature*, which carries the sense of eventual completion... but all of these work pretty well... maybe think of a very similar product, or otherwise search for a manual that will have the same problem, to convince yourself if it is normal.  I think you will be fine with these words, probably.

Comment: Maybe *finishes*, if the process is pretty short.

Comment: _Mature_ is perfect match! The process can be quite long, but we work step by step towards completion.

Comment: Or *completes*... my point being that you have a little leeway with those, especially with *"as"*... as you finish up, as you complete the process.. tough for me to say without seeing it

Comment: Glad if it helps; you might want to use a little caution with *mature*... look at some examples... often you see it with some investment that only becomes available after some set time.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. It seems to work since the "shape" of the object evolving does not change, but states within it does. I feel _mature_ perfectly describes such an evolution.